# Have I ever seen my name?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, limerick

I'm inside karma coming home
My name is a palindrome
However, have I
Ever seen my
Name in a holy tome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer to the final rhetorical question might be:

> Yes

As I wonder if the name in question is:

> **EVE**

*I'm inside karma coming home*

> Someone who wishes to seek R**EVE**NGE on someone for an action committed against them might perceive such an outcome as *karma coming home*, a wrong being righted. 'Revenge' contains the three-letter sequence 'EVE'.

*My name is a palindrome*

> 'EVE' is a palindromic woman's name, reading the same backwards as forwards.

*However, have I*
*Ever seen my*
*Name in a holy tome?*

> And if the name is 'Eve' then the answer to this question is 'Yes' since Eve certainly appears in the book of Genesis in the Bible (and presumably its equivalent in the Jewish Scriptures also).
>
>  What's more it also appears in plain sight in these lines and the title, within the words 'How**eve**r' and '**Eve**r'...

Comment: The name also appears rot13(vafvqr gung bs gur obbx bs Eriryngvba).